# Convergence of joint moments: r.v. + $o_p(1)$

Tags: probability, self-study, convergence, joint-distribution, slutsky-theorem

Consider $X_n$ a random variable that converges in distribution to $X$ and $R_n = o_p(1)$. Then, by Slutsky's $X_n + R_n \rightarrow_d X$. I already proved that for a function $f$ continuous, nonlinear, unbounded $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}E[f(X_n)] = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}E[f(X_n + R_n)] = E[f(X)]$$ and that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}E[f^2(X_n)] = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}E[f^2(X_n + R_n)] = E[f^2(X)].$$
Now I would like to prove that

$$E[f(X_n + R_n)f(X_n)] \rightarrow E[f^2(X)]$$

I cannot use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality since I am not interested by an inequality sign but I need an "=".

Does anyone has an idea on how to proceed?

My idea would by to bound the product as

$$f(X_n + R_n)f(X_n + R_n) \leq f(X_n + R_n)f(X_n) \leq f(X_n)f(X_n) .$$

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: I don't think you have enough control over $f$ to succeed.  Perhaps if you were to assume $f$ is *uniformly continuous* you could carry this through.  That would rule out problematic functions like $f:(0,\pi/2)\to\mathbb R,$ $f(x)=\sin(1/x)/x$ that can vary wildly even in small intervals.

Comment: If I assume that f is monotone increasing/decreasing then I should be able to bound as I wanted. I don't see why uniformly continuous function should help my to extend a bit the class of functions?

Comment: What about using the conditional expectation: $E[E(f(X_n)f(X_n + R_n) | X_n] = E[f(X_n) E[f(X_n + R_n)|X_n]]$ ?